# Prove that if $G$ has an odd length cycle then there cannot be a morphism from $G$ to $M$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

$G = (V, E)$ and $M = (Z, E)$ are the (infinite) graphs with vertex set $Z$, and edge set $E = \{i, i + 1\}$.

As far as I understand, since the edge set in $Z$ contains $i+1$ edges and is not strictly odd, a morphism cannot exist from a graph that has a strictly odd number of edges. I am new to understanding the combinatorial applications of graph theory and graph theory in general. Any suggestion of resources that would aid my understanding of basic graph theory would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No, the edge set of $M$ is infinite: for each integer $n$ it contains an edge $\{n,n+1\}$. It’s a chain graph that is infinite in both directions:

```
  ---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---*---
    -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4
```

And $G$ does not necessarily have a finite number of edges, let alone an odd number: what we want to show is that if $G$ has an odd **cycle**, then there is no morphism from $G$ to $M$. You can do this by showing that if $n$ is odd, there is no morphism from the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) $C_n$ to $M$.

HINT: There is a morphism from $M$ to $K_2$, the complete graph on $2$ vertices; there is no morphism from an odd cycle to $K_2$.